# Валидация ФИО javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, регулярные-выражения

У меня естьформа которая проверяется на пустую строку, но мне нужно еще проверить на соответствие символов: чтоб только буквы, разного регистра, без цифр, английские, русские, украинские, без символов, но можно было писать ъ ї такие буквы. Я так понимаю, что нужно писать регулярное выражение, не получается его правильно составить. Если кто то прям очень добр, подскажите еще как в такую валидацию добавить проверку email. Спасибо всем за подсказки и помощь!

```js
function validateForm() {

    if (document.myForm.Name.value == "" && document.myForm.Name.value == !/^[А-Я][а-я]*/ ) {

        document.myForm.Name.focus();
        var elements = document.getElementsByName("Name")[0];
        elements.className += " input_error";
        return false;

    } else {
        var elementsOk = document.getElementsByName("Name")[0];
        elementsOk.classList.remove("input_error");
    }
}
```

```html
<form class="contact-form" name="myForm" onsubmit="validateForm();" id="form">
        <div class="contact-form__item">
          <input class="contact-form__input" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Имя Фамилия">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form__item">
          <input class="contact-form__input" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form__item">
          <input class="btn-main contact-form__submit" type="submit" value="Бесплатная Консультация">
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: вспомнилось [Заблуждения программистов об именах](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/)

Answer (score 1):

я бы вот так сделал наверное. Просто добавить в регулярку недостающие симловы

```
/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁІіЇїЄєҐґ']?$/
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72212/discussion-between-koroche-vot-and-max).